# Intellij gwt - war exploded artifact

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, artifact

I see that intellij compiles *.cache.html files into .IntelliJIdea11\system\gwt**\compile\www*

But it wont copy them with the war exploded artifact.
It copies many other files like png, js and some htmls but not the generated html files.

How do I make them to be copied, otherwise my app wont work...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the artifact settings in Project Structure dialog and double-click on 'GWT Compiler output' element in 'Available Elements' tree to add GWT output to the artifact configuration.

Comment: I did that. I am getting this way the javascript files generated. But not the generated html files

Comment: Do you mean that *.cache.png files are copied but *.cache.html files are not? It's very strange. Please make sure that *.html files are not mentioned in Settings | 'File Types' | 'Ignore files and folders'.